# Fallo en el proyecto de Exist

Tags: java, exists

Tengo instalado exist el cliente java y la colecion, al intentar conectar neatbeans con la BD peta. Os dejo mi codigo y el error que me da

```
public class Conexion {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String driver = "org.exist.xmldb.DatabaseImpl"; //Driver
    Class cl = Class.forName(driver);//Cargar el driver
    Database database = (Database) cl.newInstance(); //Instancia de la BD
    DatabaseManager.registerDatabase(database); //Registrar la BD
    Collection col =DatabaseManager.getCollection("xmldb:exist://localhost:8080/eXist/xmlrpc", "admin", "admin");
    XPathQueryService service =(XPathQueryService) col.getService("XPathQueryService", "1.0");        
    //Consulta a lanzar
    ResourceSet result = service.query("for $b in doc('colecciones.xml')//a return $b");
    ResourceIterator i = result.getIterator();
    while (i.hasMoreResources()) { //Procesamos el resultado
        Resource r = i.nextResource();
        System.out.println((String) r.getContent());
    }
}
```

}

Este es el error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
    at org.exist.xmldb.DatabaseImpl.<clinit>(DatabaseImpl.java:71)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at Conexion.main(Conexion.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 4 more
C:\Users\ck\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\debug.xml:83: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 10 seconds)
```

Comment: Según entiendo yo, no te está encontrando el lombok -> log4.j para añadirlo al .jar/war. La BD no tiene nada que ver, ¿ añadiste en el pom.xml la dependencia e instalaste en el netbeans el lombok?

Comment: no solo meti las librerias de exist tal y como pone el temario que mas hay que instalar?

Comment: mi proyecto no trae pon.xml